# List of Phrasal Verbs

Tags: verb, preposition, resource

I'm looking for a list of German phrasal verbs and their corresponding cases. The list should be as comprehensive as possible.

**EDIT** Following Takkat's answer. The concept of phrasal verbs apparently does not apply to German. In that case, I guess what I'm really looking for is a list of verbs which take a prepositional object, and the appropriate cases. For example, *denken an+A, bitten um + A, warnen vor + D*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dictionary like [Pons](http://de.pons.com/) will give you a list of possible prepositions and cases that can be used together with a particular verb, and the meaning as well, if you look up the English translation.

Pons also provide a [PDF document for download](http://de.pons.com/daten/pdf/Praxis-Grammatik/01_Verben_mit_Praepositionen.pdf) with some common verb - preposition combinations and examples of their usage.

It should be pretty comprehensive, but I don't think you can extract the information as a complete list of all these verbs. There are quite a few verbs that take propositions, so I think you'd end up with a substantial part of the dictionary anyway. Maybe you can find a free dictionary with similar information.

Comment: For linux or mac users, this command converts this pdf into a list of "phrasal verbs" `curl -L http://de.pons.com/daten/pdf/Praxis-Grammatik/01_Verben_mit_Praepositionen.pdf | pdftotext  - -  | grep -E '( bei| über| an| von| zu| auf| mit| für| nach| aus| unter| vor)$'` unfortunately copyright law prevents me from uploading his list directly.

Answer (score 7):

There is not such a concept as the phrasal verbs in German. Closest to this may be the concept of a *[Partikelverb](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb)*, known as a composition of a verb with other compounds such as a preposition, a noun, another verb, or an adjective.

More commonly used is the classification into ["separable" and "non-separable" verbal compositions](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Verb.html?lang=de). For separable verbs canoo.net offers a nice alphabetical list of at present over 9000 verbs:

- [canoo.net: Trennbare Verben](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Controller?service=inflectionRules&filter=VerbSeparable&inflectionClass=Trennbare%20Verben&entryClass=Cat%20V)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know phrasal verb is the wrong concept. I've modified my question to reflect this. I believe it is a separate entity from separable verbs; am I wrong here?

Comment: Knowing that the Partikelverb is the preferred formalism of linguists is very useful. Linguistics models don't defined reality just describe it. I'd say a "prepositional partikelverb" is pretty close to a phrasal verb :).

Answer (score 0):

In der deutschen Grammatikterminologie ist der englische Begriff phrasal verbs nicht gebräuchlich; wurde bereits oben gesagt. Man spricht von Komposita. Sie können einen Akkusativ anschließen oder einen Fall mit Präposition (den ich allgemein als Präpositiv bezeichne; nur mein persönlicher Begriff). "intransitiv" ist mir viel zu vage, da das eine Verbkonstruktion ohne Akkusativ- oder Präpositivobjekt sein kann oder eine Konstruktion mit Präpositivobjekt.
Die wichtige Verbgruppe Infinitivverben (Verb + Infinitivanschluß) hat leider keinen speziellen Namen. In englischen Lexika werden Infinitivverben einfach unter vtr geführt. Eine unschöne Art und Weise, die nicht gerade Übersichtlichkeit schafft.
Ich frage mich, welchen didaktischen Zweck eine Liste aller Komposita mit Präpositiv haben kann. Ein Lerner kann mit solchen Mammutlisten, die vielleicht 20 Prozent des Lexikons umfassen, wenig anfangen.