# hielten + für (the use of the preposition für)

Tags: preposition

I was reading the following sentence:

> Die meisten Studierenden hielten den Präsidenten für unglaubwürdig.

and I read on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halten#German) that

halten + für means **to consider, to regard**

but I know from previous studies that für is the preposition "for", so my question is:

What is the use for the preposition für? Is it simply an element of Old German that has been accepted with time?

Answer (score 1):

[Following this rule](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment?cb=1), I merge the information from the comment into an answer.

"*Etwas halten für*" is a phrasal verb. These exist in English, too. They aren't too common in German as there are prefixed verbs for the same purpose, but some exist nevertheless. See [phrasal verbs](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17696/list-of-phrasal-verbs). An example of a phrasal verb in English: "take for", or even the more exact translation in this meaning, "confuse sth. *for* sth."